# Copy file names to clipboard but skip file extensions

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I'm using this script in the batch file I created to copy the filenames to clipboard then I can use,

```
@echo off
set dirpath=%1
dir %dirpath% /b /n | clip
exit
```

I created a shortcut in Windows SendTo menu that directed to this batch file. When I want to copy file names in a specific folder to clipboard, I just right click on this folder then SendTo this batch file.
This works fine.

But can I improve this script by skipping the file extensions (like `.jpg`)?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution using an auxiliary file:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

>"%temp%\%~n0.txt" (
    for /F "delims=" %%G in ('dir "%~1" /b') do echo(%%~nG
)
type "%temp%\%~n0.txt"|clip

rem erase "%temp%\%~n0.txt"

exit
```

For a solution  without an auxiliary file, inspire yourself in [Assigning newline character to a variable in a batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5642300/3439404)

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~1`, `%%~nG` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (`>>`, `2>1` etc. special page) [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. But your solution worked like a charm. Thank you. Namo Amitabha.